# setTimeout Never Executes Function 2

Tags: javascript, callback

I tried to write asynchronous function calls in javascript using setTimeout

```
function async(fn, callback) {
setTimeout(function () {
    fn();
    callback();
}, 1000);
}
```

This is how the function is being called. I want function foo() to run first, and then my next function. Foo() runs successfully but the next function never comes out. Any idea?

```
async(foo(), function () {
    var check = checkField();
    alert('Check: ' + check); //somehow never comes out
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `foo` in a synchronous way, because instead of passing a reference to `foo` to the `async` function, you're calling `foo` and passing to `async` the result of `foo`, which is probably `undefined` (although just guessing here, because I don't know how `foo` looks like), so when the timeout hits and `async` tries to call `fn` it throws error that `undefined` is not a function and thus never reaches the line that calls the second callback.
You should call `async` this way:

```
async(foo, function () {
    var check = checkField();
    alert('Check: ' + check);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but what if there is a parameter for foo and I need to pass that parameter before calling async?

Comment: @ichachan In this case use `.bind` method. `async(foo.bind(null, param1, param2), function () {/*here the logic of the second callback */});`, where `param1` and `param2` are the values you want to pass to `foo`. [Documentation on bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Thanks but for some reason now foo is never called, even though the function runs successfully with the defined parameter. I make it call a dummy function instead and execute foo beforehand like this:
foo(parameter);

async(dummy), function () {
        var check = checkField();
        alert('Check: ' + check); //now this is working
    });

Comment: @ichachan Without seeing your code it's difficult to say what is the issue. Please see [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hquypa8j/) which defines two callbacks with pre-defined params. `.bind` basically defines a dummy function that calls `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass foo instead of calling it while calling async:

```
async(foo, function () {
var check = checkField();
alert('Check: ' + check); //somehow never comes out
});
```